# Perl formatted output xml

Tags: xml, formatting, perl

I need to format my output to xml. Let´s say I get number in parameters and I want that this numbers means how much spaces would be there from previous parent element. For example number 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LEVEL1>
  <LEVEL2>
    <LEVEL3/>
  </LEVEL2>
</LEVEL1>
```

or for 4:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LEVEL1>
    <LEVEL2>
        <LEVEL3/>
    </LEVEL2>
</LEVEL1>
```

I like modul XML::LibXML and is there way how can I do it in this modul? Or which modul can do this?

And one more thing, what if I want to have an option to set (or not) new line after heading? How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XML::Twig you can use `set_indent` to define the indent string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $indent_nb= shift @ARGV || 1;

my $t= XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented');
$t->set_indent( ' ' x $indent_nb);
$t->parse( \*DATA)->print;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LEVEL1>
  <LEVEL2>
    <LEVEL3/>
  </LEVEL2>
</LEVEL1>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just found 2 possible solutions for indenting in general:

1) Via XML::Twig:
http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm

2) Via XML::LibXML:
You can set the indent-length via the toString-method.

Check the description for the format-parameter here:
http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Document

Edit: Sorry, I was too fast. Your intention is to calculate the indent-size on base of the input-xml - right?

Comment: I want to set intend for output to value which I get in params but now I read in your link that: "libxml2 uses a hard-coded indentation of 2 space characters per indentation level. This value can not be altered on run-time." So I think I can´t change number of spaces in libxml so I must do it another way.

Comment: First link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML::LibXML "to_string" or "to_file" function. Both support "Format" as mentioned in [http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Document](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aDocument).
In the to_file function it is the second parameter after the filename.

> The optional $format parameter sets the indenting of the output. This
>   parameter is expected to be an integer value, that specifies that
>   indentation should be used. The format parameter can have three
>   different values if it is used:
>
> If $format is 0, than the document is dumped as it was originally
>   parsed
>
> If $format is 1, libxml2 will add ignorable white spaces, so the nodes
>   content is easier to read. Existing text nodes will not be altered
>
> If $format is 2 (or higher), libxml2 will act as $format == 1 but it
>   add a leading and a trailing line break to each text node.
>
> libxml2 uses a hard-coded indentation of 2 space characters per
>   indentation level. This value can not be altered on run-time.

you can view a small example on how to generate proper xml in perl on [my blog](http://jkperlygates.blogspot.de/2011/11/generating-proper-xml-with-perl.html).

Comment: Yes, this help me format xml but I can´t set how much space characters to use for indentation and that´s what I need.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i didn't get that.